# recursive loop in objects arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Im working with at structure that may look something like this:

```
  var data =  {
        "name": "McLaren",
        "drivers": [{
            "name": "BMW",
            "drivers": [{
                "name": "Subaru",
                "drivers": [{
                    "name": "Saab",
                    "drivers": [{
                        "name": "Lexus",
                        "drivers": []
                    }, {
                        "name": "Honda",
                        "drivers": []
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Its an object containing a `name` and an array of `drivers`. `drivers` can be empty but it always exists.

Now lets say i have the following object:

```
{
"name": "KIA", 
"drivers":[]
}
```

I need to place this object at the right place. To my help I got the following:

```
McLaren/BMW/Subaru/saab
```

So the new object should be pushed to the same array as Lexus and Honda.

I´ve been going crazy trying to figure out how to do it. I have been thinking in the following lines:

I convert the path to an array:

```
var pathArr = ["McLaren","BMW","Subaru","saab"]
```

And try to use a recursive function:

```
myFunction(newObject){

        for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++) {
          recursiveFunc(data.drivers, pathArr[i] )
        }

        var recursiveFunc(driversArr, name) {
          for (var ix = 0; ix < driversArr.length; ix++) {
            if (driversArr[ix].name === name) {        
                recursiveFunc(driversArr[ix].drivers, "HERE I NEED pathArr[1]")

            }
          }
        } 
      }
```

I feel like I am pretty close but there are some pieces missing.
Am I maybe thinking about recursion the wrong way or making it overly complicated?
Help appreciated,thanks!

EDIT:

`McLaren/BMW/Subaru/saab` indicates the path to where the new object (`KIA`) should go. So `KIA` should go in the `drivers`-arr in the object with the name `saab`.

recursiveFunc()
    checks in which array the path-name exists and the then tries to use this objects array to go deeper into the object in order to find the last part of the path (saab, in this case). The new object should be pushed to this array.

Comment: Why does `KIA` object get pushed to `Saab`? There is nothing shown to make that relationship. Also not clear what your specific problem or question is. We have no idea what `recursiveFunc()` does

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you problem, but I think you are making it more complicated than it really is. I recommend you to read about JSON basics on javascript, it may help you. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: You need an **else** statement , containing an end condition for the recursion.

Comment: What is your data model describing? A McLaren driven by a BMW driven by a Subaru driven by a Saab driven by a Lexus and a Honda? What kind of weird car universe is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea to stand by: when the data is difficult to deal with, transform your data.

I propose an alternative solution that might be a little simpler:

Create an object which contains your path as a key, and a reference to the associated driver array as the value.

```
var mapping = {};
function storeMap (chain, data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var updatedChain = (chain && chain + '/') + data[i].name;
        mapping[updatedChain] = data[i].drivers;
        if (data[i].drivers.length) {
            storeMap (updatedChain, data[i].drivers);
        }
    }
}

storeMap('', [data]);
```

Then to add your item:

```
var itemToAdd = { "name": "KIA", "drivers":[] };
var path = 'McLaren/BMW/Subaru/saab';
mapping[path].push(itemToAdd);
```

This was meant to be a once off... on the case of reusability: you'd have to run the map storing every time which isn't very efficient. What you could do is have methods that update the map as you're modifying it:

```
function addItem (item) {
    mapping[path].push(item);
    mapping[path + '/' + item.name] = item.drivers;
}

function removeItem (item) {
    var parentPath = item.name.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
    var drivers = mapping[parentPath].drivers;
    drivers.splice(drivers.indexOf(item), 1);
    delete mapping[item.name];
}
```

Comment: This was a great answer!
At first i did not understand what it did but after logging "mapping" to the console it became clearer. I will study the code to better understand the concept of mapping better. And also thank you for the reusable extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this code passing `{ drivers : [data] }` root object as `currentNode`.

```
var insert = function(currentNode, nodeToInsert, pathArr) {
    if(pathArr.length == 0) {
        currentNode.drivers.push(nodeToInsert);
        return true;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < currentNode.drivers.length; i++)
        if(currentNode.drivers[i].name == pathArr[0])
            return insert(currentNode.drivers[i], nodeToInsert, pathArr.splice(1));
    return false;
}
```

Note that in your example you have `Saab` in JSON and `saab` in path which will lead path search failure.

Comment: Thank you! I will see if I can get it to work with this code!

Comment: @user2915962, let me know if you encounter any problems running the code.

Comment: I tried it passing { drivers : [data] } root object as currentNode. It worked!
I do not know which answer is "the best", but i decided to accept the above answer due to the fact that I learned more from it.
I do appreciate that you took the time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution, which takes the object and the path as array.

```js
function find(object, path) {
    if (object.name.toLowerCase !== path.shift().toLowerCase) {
        return;
    }
    return (!path.length || object.drivers.some(function (a) {
        object = find(a, path.slice());
        return object;
    })) && object;
}

var data = { "name": "McLaren", "drivers": [{ "name": "BMW", "drivers": [{ "name": "VW", "drivers": [] }, { "name": "Subaru", "drivers": [{ "name": "Saab", "drivers": [{ "name": "Lexus", "drivers": [] }, { "name": "Honda", "drivers": [] }] }] }] }] },
    path = 'McLaren/BMW/Subaru/Saab',
    object = { "name": "KIA", "drivers": [] };

find(data, path.split('/')).drivers.push(object);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```